# How to convert a huge Elisp data structure to JSON?

Tags: json, recursion, emacs, elisp, org-mode

[`org-element-parse-buffer`](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) returns a huge tree even for a small Org file. I want to transform this tree into JSON. Apparently, [`json.el`](http://edward.oconnor.cx/2006/03/json.el) uses recursive functions to traverse cons cells, and as Elisp doesn't support [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), invocation of `json-encode` quickly runs out of stack. If I increase `max-lisp-eval-depth` and `max-specpdl-size`, Emacs crashes.

How do I workaround that and transform a huge tree structure into JSON? In general, how do I workaround when I have a huge data structure and a recursive function that may run out of stack?

Comment: I would submit a bug report for json.el -- recursion in arbitrary data structures in elisp is a bad idea for the reason you've indicated.

Comment: Without re-writing the code to be non-recursive, you could *maybe* hack it to watch the recursion depth, and push too-deep nodes into a queue to process subsequently, and generate tokens in the JSON at those points (for subsequent replacement when you iterate over the queue to process those sub-trees independently). That may or may not be more complicated than it sounds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `json.el` functions are recursive, but recursive functions called on Org-Element cause stack overflow not because `org-element-parse-buffer` returns a huge AST, but because it returns a [circular list](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Circular-Objects.html). A tree-recursive function on a circular list is like a squirrel in a cage.

I guess, the idea behind using self-references in the AST returns is that if you traverse it, at any point you can go back to parent by simply running `plist-get` on keyword `:parent`. I imagine this usage for traversing the AST up and down:

```
(let ((xs '#1=(:text "foo" :child (:text "bar" :parent #1#))))
  (plist-get
   (plist-get
    xs
    :child)  ; (:text "bar" :parent (:text "foo" :child #0))
   :parent)) ; (:text "foo" :child (:text "bar" :parent #0))
```

But JSON doesn't support circular lists, so you need to remove these self-references from the AST before trying to convert to any data serialization format. I haven't found the way to elegantly remove circular references in the AST, so I resorted to a dirty hack:

1. Convert the AST to a string
2. Remove references with [regular expressions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)
3. Convert the string back to an Elisp data structure

Suppose I have an Org file called `test.org` with the following content:

```
* Heading
** Subheading
Text
```

Then variable `tree` contains the parsed Org data from this buffer: `(setq tree (with-current-buffer "test.org" (org-element-parse-buffer)))`. Then to prepare this data for JSON export, I just run:

```
(car (read-from-string (replace-regexp-in-string ":parent #[0-9]+?" "" (prin1-to-string tree)))))
```

Even with all mentions of `:parent` removed, the new AST is still valid, so if the new AST is in variable `tree2`, then the following 3 expressions are equivalent:

```
(org-element-interpret-data tree2)
(with-current-buffer "test.org" (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (buffer-end 1)))
"* Heading\n** Subheading\nText\n"
```

Note that for some reason `org-element-interpret-data` removes preceding whitespace, so the above is not technically true, when you have lines like `text` in your Org file.

Now all you need to do is to encode the new non-circular AST into JSON and write it into a file:

```
(f-write (json-encode tree2) 'utf-8 "test.json")
```

#### Notes

1. Elisp's [cons cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cons) are pairs of 2 slots: `car` and `cdr`. If `cdr` of each cell contains a link to another cons cell, we get a linked list. If both `car` and `cdr` point at 2 values, we get a dotted pair. Therefore `(1 . (2 . (3 . nil)))` is equivalent to `(1 2 3)`. But a `cdr` (or `car` for that matter) might point at any other cons cell, including the one that already were earlier in the list, giving rise to [circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list).
2. *Exercise:* create a complex tree data structure with several self-references to different subtrees. Then try traversing this tree and jumping by the self-references to get the idea.
3. With [->>](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#--x-form-rest-more) threading macro from [**`dash`**](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library the expression is equivalent to:

   ```
   (->> tree prin1-to-string (replace-regexp-in-string ":parent #[0-9]+?" "") read-from-string car)
   ```
4. `(buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (buffer-end 1))` is like `(buffer-string)`, but without annoying [text properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html) attached.
5. [`f-write`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-write-text-text-coding-path) is a function that writes text to files from [**`f`**](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) third-party file manipulation library.

Comment: "Like a squirrel in a cage"?

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr*

Here's how to remove references to parent and structure in an org tree before encoding it to json :

```lisp
 (let* ((tree (org-element-parse-buffer 'object nil)))
    (org-element-map tree (append org-element-all-elements
                                  org-element-all-objects '(plain-text))
      (lambda (x)
        (if (org-element-property :parent x)
            (org-element-put-property x :parent "none"))
        (if (org-element-property :structure x)
            (org-element-put-property x :structure "none"))))
    (json-encode tree))
```